# Inequalities with factors

Tags: inequality

When I study $x^2\geq0$ I draw the parabola and say that it's for all x, without making any table with zero.
Why when I study $x^2(x^2-1)\geq0$, must I insert $0$ in the sign table? And say that the solution is $x\leq-1 \vee x=0 \vee x\geq1$.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case $0$ is not in the interval that you find by studying where $x^2-1$ is positive (which is $(-\infty, - 1]\cup [1,+\infty)$) so you have to add it to the interval where the whole function $x^2 (x^2-1)$ is positive (which is $(-\infty, - 1]\cup \{0\}\cup [1,+\infty)$)   because it comes from the first term, $x^2$.

Comment: Just as I thought, thanks. This happens only when I have factors or also in other cases, for example N and D?

Comment: @Veronica B you're welcome. It happens when you have several factors and so also in the case of fractions of functions (I interpreted your "N and D" as referring to the case of a function of the form $\frac{N} {D} $ where $N$ and $D$ are themselves functions).